# How to separate 2 Output data using line in java

Tags: javascript, javadoc, java

(Sorry for my mistakes in spelling)
output came from .cvs file

> "First Name","Last Name","Main-Email","Current Employer","Internal Contact ID","PSI Club Member Nbr.","Membership Type","Membership Status","Member Since","Membership Card Sent","Membership Start Date","Membership Expiration Date","Nationality 1","Membership ID"
>   "Pierre","ABT","piero.a@bluewin.ch",,"1655","1350","Resident Renewal","Active","1968-01-01","February 10th, 2011","1968-01-01","1968-12-31",,"1915"
>   "Bruno","ADAM","bruno.adam@bluewin.ch","OCTAVE GROUP","1656","5288","Resident Renewal","Active","2012-01-01","February 16th, 2012","2012-01-01","2012-12-31","France","424

```
i want output in this way..separate line between each data.How to do frnds..


 here is my code can any guide me..thanks in advance.
"Bruce", |"ADAMS", |"bruce.adams@bluewin.ch",|,"1657",|"883",|"Resident  Renewal",|"Active",|"2011-05-10",|,"2012-01-01",|"2012-12-31",|"Canada",
         |         |                         |               |                   | 
         |         |                         |               |                   |



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FileRead {
/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
String fileName="C:/Users/Desktop/cvsFile.csv";
try {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(fileName));
String strLine = null;
StringTokenizer st = null;
int lineNumber = 0, tokenNumber = 0;
while( (fileName = br.readLine()) != null)
{
lineNumber++;

  /* String[] result = fileName.split("[\r\n]+");
for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++) {
    System.out.println(result[x]);*/


//break comma separated line using ","
st = new StringTokenizer(fileName, "|");
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
//display csv values
tokenNumber++;
System.out.println("Line # " + lineNumber + " Token : "+ st.nextToken());
}
//reset token number
tokenNumber = 0;
}
 //  }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

[image]

Is tr any option to do above image output in java..
I want d Output in this way. can any one guide me.. above there is a code...
In middle i need line that separate the Output data. 
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just replace comma with the new separator like:

```
str.replace(",", ",|,");
```

Comment: Use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`!

Comment: meant to run the entire Input.

Comment: Write this in the processing routine into the whole loop For each read line, or simplier you can read the entire file into a string then run this once over the rntire strign using replaceAll()

Comment: @O.D `replaceAll()` is used if you need to use a regular expressions in the paramters, while `replace()` will also replace all matched strings but it's not using regex.

Comment: @O.D is it possible to do output data as shown in image.

Comment: @fresher you will need to set a constant fied lenghh to get a well formated output

Comment: @O.D hi, i am getting message when i press ASK QUESTION. Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.   HOW TO RECOVER MY ACCOUNT please sujject me..